# what is i have to use instead gnome desktop environment to run virtual keyboard on i.mx6 using qt?

Tags: linux, qt, virtual-keyboard

I have used open source code of florence virtual keyboard on qt5. but due to ima not using GNOME desktop environment this key board not receiving any released key of virtual keyboard on lcd connected to I.mx6.

i am using Linux 4.9.88-10183-ge88eca2 #12 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 17 01:16:19 CDT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux os. i am using Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) .

I have installed all require package mention on below site

http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/install.html

But i am not receiving released key character on QLine edit.

when i run florence it shows o/p log :

Your screen does not support alpha channel. Semi-transparency is disabled DBus name aquired: org.florence.Keyboard

When i am installing other virtual keyboard and when i open keyboard, at that time "x" symbol come on screen. when i touch any character it cursor indicator shows "x".

what is meaning of this "x" means ?

when i install third party virtual keyboard plug in on linux pc it works fine but when i try run it on customized os on embedded processor at that time this keyboard get open but it just get open and but on click of keyboard key it not respond.

why this happen ? what is technical reason behind that ? How to resolve it?

Comment: Does it happen on your app specifically, or is it a repeatable pattern for system-provided apps, too?

Comment: It happens to all 3rd part virtual keyboard apps